# Using Unicode in Boost Python with a C++ function that takes std::wstring

Tags: python, c++, boost, unicode, boost-python

I am using the Boost Python library to wrap a C++ class I have so that I can call its methods from Python. My C++ class `Clazz` has public methods:

```
void doSomething(std::string& s) { ... }
void doSomethingWide(std::wstring& ws) { ... }
```

I've created a `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` which points to these two methods. The first one which uses `std::string` I'm able to call fine. However, when I try to call the second one with a Python Unicode string:

```
x = u'hello'
Clazz.doSomethingWide(x)
```

I get the error:

`ArgumentError: Python argument types in
  Clazz.doSomethingWide(Clazz, unicode)
did not match C++ signature:
  doSomething(Clazz, std::wstring)`

I had hoped that `unicode` would automatically interface with `std::wstring` as the regular Python string type did with `std::string`. However, this appears to not be the case.

In another thread, someone suggested first doing the conversion:

```
x = str(x.encode('utf-8'))
```

However, I am dealing with very large strings and this destroys the performance of my code since it is *O(n)* in the number of characters of `x`.

I *do* have the ability to modify the C++ library that I'm trying to interface with. Is there a way to pass in Python `unicode` types into my C++ library in a way that I can use them? I've searched the Internet far and wide and found some references to converters and other things, but implementing them did not fix the above error message (very possibly I'm not using them correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, type conversions generally result in rvalue objects, and thus the parameters must either accept by value or by const reference.  Hence, change:

```cpp
void doSomethingWide(std::wstring&);
```

to either of the following:

```cpp
void doSomethingWide(std::wstring);
void doSomethingWide(const std::wstring&);
```

---

Boost.Python added [`std::wstring` conversions](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/news.html) on 11-SEP-2003.  As a general rule, when type conversions occur in Boost.Python, the resulting object is treated as an rvalue.  This behavior is indirectly noted in the [`boost::python::extract`](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/v2/extract.html#extract-spec-observers) observer specification:

> Converts the stored pointer to `result_type`, which is either `T` or  `T const&`.

If lvalue conversions were supported, it could introduce awkward semantics for some types.  For example, immutable Python strings could be modified by C++ functions.

---

Here is a complete minimal example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

class spam
{
public:
  void doSomething(const std::string& str)
  {
    std::cout << "spam::doSomething(): " << str << std::endl;
  }

  void doSomethingWide(const std::wstring& str)
  {
    std::wcout << "spam::doSomethingWide(): " << str << std::endl;
  }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<spam>("Spam")
    .def("doSomething", &spam::doSomething)
    .def("doSomethingWide", &spam::doSomethingWide)
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> spam = example.Spam()
>>> spam.doSomething("test")
spam::doSomething(): test
>>> spam.doSomethingWide(u"test")
spam::doSomethingWide(): test
```